# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf7 in position 4: invalid start byte

Tags: python, utf-8, decode, codec

```
import socket
import os
import mimetypes
import threading

content_types={
    '.html': 'text/html',
    '.css': 'text/css',
    '.jpg': 'image/jpeg',
    '.jpeg': 'image/jpeg',
    '.png': 'image/png',
    '.txt': 'text/plain'
}
HTTP_METHODS = {
    'GET',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
    'DELETE'
}


def handle_request(client):

    request = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    lines = request.split("\r\n")
    request_line = lines[0].split(" ")
    method = request_line[0]
    path = request_line[1]


    if method == 'GET':
        handle_get(client,path)
    elif method == 'POST':
        content = lines[-1]
        handle_post(client,path,content.encode())
    elif method == 'PUT':
        content = lines[-1]
        handle_put(client,path,content.encode())
    elif method == 'DELETE':
        handle_delete(client,path)
    else:
        response = 'HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request\n\nUnsupported HTTP method'

    client.sendall(response.encode())
    client.close()
def handle_delete(client_socket, path):
        # Delete the requested file
        os.remove(path)

        # Send a 200 OK response
        response_headers = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n'
        client_socket.send(response_headers.encode())
        client.close()
def run_server():

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    server_socket.bind(('localhost', 8189))

    server_socket.listen(1)
    print("The server will start on port 8189 ")

    while True :
        client, adress = server_socket.accept()
        handle_request(client)
run_server()
```

I have this code that I have written above, and I am receiving a

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf7 in position 4: invalid start byte

error whenever I try to make any type of requests. I know there is `handle_get` function and `handle_put` that I want to add but I don't know where is the problem with the encoding and decoding.

Comment: Have you checked the headers? It's not uncommon for the text to be encoded in something other than UTF-8. e.g. `cp1252` aka Windows-1252 is quite common for historical reasons; if they sent a `÷`, and it was encoded in `cp1252`, it would produce `0xf7`.